# Query for grouping columns with the same text in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database, 'users' and 'accounts'.

Each have a column named 'email'

What I would like to do in the end is query 'users' and return all the rows which do NOT have the same email as one of the rows in 'accounts', and then DROP those entire rows.

I started by trying to craft a query which returned all the rows in 'users' that DO have an email that exists in one of the rows in 'accounts'

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE users.email = accounts.email
```

This gave me an error using the syntax "users.email".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

To clarify, my problem was that I had devices(users) which were being registered to my database by people who had not created an account (uniquely identified by their email address). These devices were still being registered with email addresses, just not those belonging to a legitimate account, so email will never be null. I wanted to form a query that returns all the rows of 'users' whose email column does not match any email in the 'accounts' table, so that I could then drop those users.

I solved this problem in a more simple way just using PHP, but for the sake of answering my original question: 
What I was trying to is essentially the opposite of this:

```
SELECT email
FROM users
JOIN accounts
ON users.email=accounts.email;
```

That query would return all of the rows of users that do have an email that also exists in the email column of the accounts table, meaning the device is registered to a legitimate account. I wanted to do the opposite, a query which would return the rows of all users whose email field in 'user' does not match with any email field in 'accounts', so that I could then drop those devices.

Comment: Well the problem with the query is that you are already in table `users` so you don't need to say `users.email` you would just say `email = 'someemail@email.com'` The second problem is that accounts.email will not work because you are selecting from `users`

Comment: The error near `users.email` is probably `accounts`.  You have a table alias that is not defined in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a list of users that do not have corresponding email address in accounts, you can use a left join where accounts email is null.

Putting that in a subselect for a delete will allow you to delete all the rows that are in users that are not in accounts.  (i've commented out the delete for safety)

```
select *
--delete 
from
  `users`
where `users`.email in (
    select u.email
    from
      `users` u
       left join `accounts` a on u.email = a.email
    where
      a.email is null)
```

You can see this working in a <kbd>[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/701fd9/3)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. Even though this doesn't accomplish exactly what I'm looking for, I'll accept it since what I originally wanted may not be logically possible.

Comment: @user3878723 Thank you, but if you clarify your question, i'll be happy to dig in further.  No use having an answer out there that doesnt solve an actual problem.

Comment: Please see edit. An approach like this could work, but the email field will never be null. It is an invalid email in the 'email' field of the 'users' table if no such email exists in the 'email' column in the 'accounts' table.

Comment: @user3878723, the email field will be null in the result set coming from a left join. Check out the sql fiddle from either paqogomez's answer or mine, an example of this null return value is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67050/26. His answer does work and is simpler than mine

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is a `join` statement

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

is how you get the = from another table

There is an example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for wall of text. Let me start from here:

> I wanted to form a query that returns all the rows of 'users' whose email column does not match any email in the 'accounts' table, so that I could then drop those users.

I think you need to solve the problem first, and make sure they are sent a verification email with a link they must click on during the sign-up process. You won't get this problem anymore.

**Now, The query you're looking for**

> That query would return all of the rows of users that do have an email that also exists in the email column of the accounts table ...  It is an invalid email in the 'email' field of the 'users' table if no such email exists in the 'email' column in the 'accounts' table.

If I understand you correctly, You'll want to do a subquery of the records(email addresses) that exist in both tables. Then, from that query you will select only the ones do not have an email in the accounts table. What would really help us all understand is a mock-up on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

I made a mockup below, I make a query that returns a result like this: (let me explain the variables first)

...

exist_in_both.aemail #=> email exist in both, found in account table

exist_in_both.uemail #=> email exists in both, found in user table

email #=> email that does NOT exist in both

... Results of the query from here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67050/26 looks like:

```
exist_in_both.aemail, exist_in_both.uemail, email
```

Now, I make query against THOSE results, and only select the ones that have the column for existing in a single table, but not a full column for existing in both tables. That looks like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67050/38

Your needed query, returns emails that exist only in the accounts table, but not emails that exist in both users table and accounts table. A, b, and c are in accounts, a and b are in users, this will select c. :)

```
SELECT derived_table.email from (select * 
  from (
    SELECT u.email as uemail, a.email as aemail 
    from users u join accounts a 
    WHERE u.email = a.email) exist_in_both
  RIGHT JOIN accounts on accounts.email = exist_in_both.aemail) derived_table
WHERE derived_table.uemail IS NULL
```

Working from the inside out: You select the emails that exist in both, then you do a right join to the emails that exist in just one table. Then, from that result set you query the ones that are emails that didn't show up in the results for "exists in both".

In the unfortunate situation that you have emails that exist in accounts that don't exist in users, AND you have emails that exist in users that don't exist in accounts, here's a SQL fiddle where that situation is going on, and the query to solve that problem. (just with a UNION) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed2814/1

Comment: Excellent and very comprehensive summary.